# "turn them all off" or "turn all them off"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

"turn them all off" 84,800 results

"turn all them off" 63,200 results

both are correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second is INCORRECT. (unless that was a typo)

The phrase "turn all **of** them off" is correct, however.

The stress is different in these two phrases, however. For most uses, the difference between these two is quite subtle, so nothing to worry about.

In the second phrase you can put the emphasis on "THEM"

So, you could say: "Turn all of THEM off" (pointing to a specific set of light switches)

Using the first phrase in like manner sounds awkward.

Comment: "Turn all of THEM off" 772,000 results. You win!

Comment: Uh, I believe I said the same thing Atomix did, just a few minutes earlier than he did.

Comment: @Matha: but Atømix provided a more detailed answer.

Comment: @Steve Melnikoff, I have no problem with this answer being chosen as 'best'. My objection/puzzlement is regarding the "You win" comment. Yes, "turn all of them off" wins the Google war, but how is this a win for Atømix when I suggested it first?

Comment: Don't worry Martha. I will upvote your answer. As it was useful as well. After all, that's the criteria. If an answer is useful, then you upvote it. The "Accepted Answer" is the just the one that the OP found most useful. One vote is worth "10" "Accepted is only worth 15"

Answer (score 4):

"Turn them all off" and "Turn all of them off" are both correct, but there's a slight difference in meaning, or at least in emphasis. "Turn all them off" is informal usage at best.